# Чем отличается наследование

Tags: c++

Чем отличается

```
struct A
{
};
struct B : public A
{
};
```

от

```
struct A
{
};
struct B : A
{
};
```

?

Answer (score 3):

Ничем не отличается. При наследовании структур наследованием по умолчанию является *public*. При наследовании классов — *private*.

Та же ситуация и с полями.

```
class A {
    int a; // private
};

struct A {
    int a; //public
};
```

Comment: Если `struct B` заменить на `class B` и пытаться вызвать функцию унаследованную от `struct A`, то получим разные результаты в двух случаях вопроса